# Custom selector for list background

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to set some custom selector states to every item in my listview. I have tried the following"

list_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/row_selected_background" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/row_selected_background" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/row_selected_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/row_background" />
</selector>
```

list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/row_background"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reason, the list unselected background color is as it is defined. But the on pressed/click is always the default android holo blue for a list. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `android:state_pressed` to specify pressed states.

---

Drawable to use: `/res/drawable/bg.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

Selector to use: `/res/drawable/item.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg"/>
</selector>
```

ListView:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:saveEnabled="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/item"
    />
```

Result on pressing a list item:

[image]

Note: List selector is drawn behind Item View, Item View may have its own background.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**

first set the `row_selector.xml`

**Step 2 :**
apply the selector to the items as

```
android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
```

**Step 3 :**
Make a selector for the list, `list_selector.xml` with all the states transparent to get rid of the default states.

**Step 4 :**
apply the selector to the listview as

`android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"`

Comment: sorry thats just a typo

Comment: how do i set all states to transparent?

Comment: android:drawable="@color/android:transparent"