# List View highlight selected row

Tags: android, listview, adapter, highlight, listviewitem

I need to highlight the selected row in list view once we select the item.

Eg : I select first item its gets highlighted, if i select 3rd item then remove 1st item highlighted and then highlight 3rd item.

I have seen many examples and questions posted in Stackoverflow but havent found a proper solution.

Below is my code, it works but i need to select the item twice to get highlighted, how can i modify this to work smoothly ?

```
ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

        // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
        planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                          "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune",
                                          "Ceres","Pluto","Haumea","Makemake","Eris"};    
        planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

        planetsAdapter = new PlanetsAdapter (this,planetList);
        planetsAdapter .setNotifyOnChange(true);

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        mainListView.setAdapter(planetsAdapter );
        mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                planetsAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
                planetsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Adapted Class :

```
public class PlanetsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private ArrayList<String> planets;
        private Context mContext = null;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        // used to keep selected position in ListView
        private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected

        public PlanetsAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context,0,objects);
            mContext = context;
            planets = objects;
        }

        public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
            selectedPos = pos;
            // inform the view of this change
        }

        public int getSelectedPosition(){
            return selectedPos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);

            // change the row color based on selected state
            if(position == selectedPos){
                //title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                title.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ED07E1"));
            }else{
                //title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                title.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e2e2e2"));
            }

            title.setText(getItem(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**Edit : Answered Below**

```
For anyone who is looking for answers, i have answered it below hope it helps.
```

Comment: Try to add `notifyDataSetChanged();` to `setSelectedPosition` in your Adapter

Comment: @MD Have tried that before but still i need to select the item twice to get highlighted.

Comment: your question is not understable to me. `select the item twice to get highlighted`.

Comment: @MD The code that i have show highlights the row or item, but for the first time it will not get highlighted, on selecting the same item again it gets highlighted.

Comment: @user2056563 are you extend your activity to ListActivity?

Comment: @Naruto No i am not extending ListActivity

Comment: @user2056563 then tell me which one you are extending your mainactivity

Comment: @user2056563 Check like `if(selectedPos!=-1  && selectedPos== position){`

Comment: its just a class which extends Activity

Comment: I have tried this as well if(selectedPos!=-1 && selectedPos== position){ but still the same result.

Comment: I have solved it just have a look at it,

Answer (score 0):

Set this into your listview (xml or code)

```
XML: android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

code: mListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

In your xml, try to add android:listSelector background for the feedback to your selection.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html

Comment: No it will not highlight the row, it just indicates that user has selected that item

Comment: Do you define the background selector drawable for your item view, and does it have this: android:state_activated or android:state_selected .

Comment: Yes i have done , i have refered to link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386035/custom-selector-for-list-background

Comment: I would like to know how did you define you listview in the xml and how THE ITEM VIEW xml's defined. The selector will be drawn under the item background (if it has one), so your definition will help. Since listview is an adapter view, I think the approach in your adapter is not what we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research and R&D finally got the solution :

List View in Activity or Fragment :

```
ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

        // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
        planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                          "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune",
                                          "Ceres","Pluto","Haumea","Makemake","Eris"};    
        planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

        planetsAdapter = new PlanetsAdapter (this,planetList);
        planetsAdapter .setNotifyOnChange(true);

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        mainListView.setAdapter(planetsAdapter );
        mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true); //Important
            }
        });
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class PlanetsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private ArrayList<String> planets;
        private Context mContext = null;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;


        public PlanetsAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<String> objects) {
            super(context,0,objects);
            mContext = context;
            planets = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);

            title.setText(getItem(position));//Set the text to textview
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

ListView defined in XML :

```
<ListView
                    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
                </ListView>
```

Each List Item defined in xml `list_item.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
 android:padding="5dp"  
 android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
 android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
 android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

Note in the above code i have used 2 different selectors one for background and one for changing the text color.

list_item_selector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/defalut_color" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/defalut_color" android:state_activated="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

text_color_selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#000000" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:color="#000000" android:state_activated="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="defalut_color">#e2e2e2</color>
<color name="pressed_color">#ED07E1</color>
</resources>
```

So thats it enjoy :)

Comment: This is what Nguyễn Hoài Nam had suggested.