# Android: How to change the background color when user selected the item in the listview.

Tags: android, listview, select, background

I have problem with the background color when user selected the item in the listview. I can see the highlight changed when user pressing it but once released it went back to normal color.

This is my selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/grey_light"/>
<item  
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@color/grey"/>
```

This is my xml file using the above selector.

```
<ListView
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/preview_button_selector"
    android:id="@+id/previewList"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This is my code

```
public void ThumbnailList_ItemClicked (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) {

        args.View.Selected = true;

        var previewViewPager = (ViewPager)FindViewById (Resource.Id.previewViewPager);
        previewViewPager.SetCurrentItem (args.Position, true); 

    }
```

Does anyone know why I can't get the background color stays when selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        ... //Anything
    }
});
```

Comment: @Simon see the answer.

Comment: I used xamarin and my code did have view.setSelected as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with selectors.
Look at this post , this should do the effect :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386173/4035864

Hopefully I could help

Comment: I realized it was my viewpager code in the onItemClick section. When I commented that line , selection background changed and stays. But it need that lines too....

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

to your `listView`